# Material Design Icons Full Raw List

Tags: icons, material-design

Just in case someone needs this raw list of Material Design Icons. The best way to use these icons on the web is with the icon web font. It's lightweight, easy to use, and hosted by Google Web Fonts.

Answer (score 1):

```
3d_rotation
ac_unit
access_alarm
access_alarms
access_time
accessibility
accessible
account_balance
account_balance_wallet
account_box
account_circle
adb
add
add_a_photo
add_alarm
add_alert
add_box
add_circle
add_circle_outline
add_location
add_shopping_cart
add_to_photos
add_to_queue
adjust
airline_seat_flat
airline_seat_flat_angled
airline_seat_individual_suite
airline_seat_legroom_extra
airline_seat_legroom_normal
airline_seat_legroom_reduced
airline_seat_recline_extra
airline_seat_recline_normal
airplanemode_active
airplanemode_inactive
airplay
airport_shuttle
alarm
alarm_add
alarm_off
alarm_on
album
all_inclusive
all_out
android
announcement
apps
archive
arrow_back
arrow_downward
arrow_drop_down
arrow_drop_down_circle
arrow_drop_up
arrow_forward
arrow_upward
art_track
aspect_ratio
assessment
assignment
assignment_ind
assignment_late
assignment_return
assignment_returned
assignment_turned_in
assistant
assistant_photo
attach_file
attach_money
attachment
audiotrack
autorenew
av_timer
backspace
backup
battery_alert
battery_charging_full
battery_full
battery_std
battery_unknown
beach_access
beenhere
block
bluetooth
bluetooth_audio
bluetooth_connected
bluetooth_disabled
bluetooth_searching
blur_circular
blur_linear
blur_off
blur_on
book
bookmark
bookmark_border
border_all
border_bottom
border_clear
border_color
border_horizontal
border_inner
border_left
border_outer
border_right
border_style
border_top
border_vertical
branding_watermark
brightness_1
brightness_2
brightness_3
brightness_4
brightness_5
brightness_6
brightness_7
brightness_auto
brightness_high
brightness_low
brightness_medium
broken_image
brush
bubble_chart
bug_report
build
burst_mode
business
business_center
cached
cake
call
call_end
call_made
call_merge
call_missed
call_missed_outgoing
call_received
call_split
call_to_action
camera
camera_alt
camera_enhance
camera_front
camera_rear
camera_roll
cancel
card_giftcard
card_membership
card_travel
casino
cast
cast_connected
center_focus_strong
center_focus_weak
change_history
chat
chat_bubble
chat_bubble_outline
check
check_box
check_box_outline_blank
check_circle
chevron_left
chevron_right
child_care
child_friendly
chrome_reader_mode
class
clear
clear_all
close
closed_caption
cloud
cloud_circle
cloud_done
cloud_download
cloud_off
cloud_queue
cloud_upload
code
collections
collections_bookmark
color_lens
colorize
comment
compare
compare_arrows
computer
confirmation_number
contact_mail
contact_phone
contacts
content_copy
content_cut
content_paste
control_point
control_point_duplicate
copyright
create
create_new_folder
credit_card
crop
crop_16_9
crop_3_2
crop_5_4
crop_7_5
crop_din
crop_free
crop_landscape
crop_original
crop_portrait
crop_rotate
crop_square
dashboard
data_usage
date_range
dehaze
delete
delete_forever
delete_sweep
description
desktop_mac
desktop_windows
details
developer_board
developer_mode
device_hub
devices
devices_other
dialer_sip
dialpad
directions
directions_bike
directions_boat
directions_bus
directions_car
directions_railway
directions_run
directions_subway
directions_transit
directions_walk
disc_full
dns
do_not_disturb
do_not_disturb_alt
do_not_disturb_off
do_not_disturb_on
dock
domain
done
done_all
donut_large
donut_small
drafts
drag_handle
drive_eta
dvr
edit
edit_location
eject
email
enhanced_encryption
equalizer
error
error_outline
euro_symbol
ev_station
event
event_available
event_busy
event_note
event_seat
exit_to_app
expand_less
expand_more
explicit
explore
exposure
exposure_neg_1
exposure_neg_2
exposure_plus_1
exposure_plus_2
exposure_zero
extension
face
fast_forward
fast_rewind
favorite
favorite_border
featured_play_list
featured_video
feedback
fiber_dvr
fiber_manual_record
fiber_new
fiber_pin
fiber_smart_record
file_download
file_upload
filter
filter_1
filter_2
filter_3
filter_4
filter_5
filter_6
filter_7
filter_8
filter_9
filter_9_plus
filter_b_and_w
filter_center_focus
filter_drama
filter_frames
filter_hdr
filter_list
filter_none
filter_tilt_shift
filter_vintage
find_in_page
find_replace
fingerprint
first_page
fitness_center
flag
flare
flash_auto
flash_off
flash_on
flight
flight_land
flight_takeoff
flip
flip_to_back
flip_to_front
folder
folder_open
folder_shared
folder_special
font_download
format_align_center
format_align_justify
format_align_left
format_align_right
format_bold
format_clear
format_color_fill
format_color_reset
format_color_text
format_indent_decrease
format_indent_increase
format_italic
format_line_spacing
format_list_bulleted
format_list_numbered
format_paint
format_quote
format_shapes
format_size
format_strikethrough
format_textdirection_l_to_r
format_textdirection_r_to_l
format_underlined
forum
forward
forward_10
forward_30
forward_5
free_breakfast
fullscreen
fullscreen_exit
functions
g_translate
gamepad
games
gavel
gesture
get_app
gif
golf_course
gps_fixed
gps_not_fixed
gps_off
grade
gradient
grain
graphic_eq
grid_off
grid_on
group
group_add
group_work
hd
hdr_off
hdr_on
hdr_strong
hdr_weak
headset
headset_mic
healing
hearing
help
help_outline
high_quality
highlight
highlight_off
history
home
hot_tub
hotel
hourglass_empty
hourglass_full
http
https
image
image_aspect_ratio
import_contacts
import_export
important_devices
inbox
indeterminate_check_box
info
info_outline
input
insert_chart
insert_comment
insert_drive_file
insert_emoticon
insert_invitation
insert_link
insert_photo
invert_colors
invert_colors_off
iso
keyboard
keyboard_arrow_down
keyboard_arrow_left
keyboard_arrow_right
keyboard_arrow_up
keyboard_backspace
keyboard_capslock
keyboard_hide
keyboard_return
keyboard_tab
keyboard_voice
kitchen
label
label_outline
landscape
language
laptop
laptop_chromebook
laptop_mac
laptop_windows
last_page
launch
layers
layers_clear
leak_add
leak_remove
lens
library_add
library_books
library_music
lightbulb_outline
line_style
line_weight
linear_scale
link
linked_camera
list
live_help
live_tv
local_activity
local_airport
local_atm
local_bar
local_cafe
local_car_wash
local_convenience_store
local_dining
local_drink
local_florist
local_gas_station
local_grocery_store
local_hospital
local_hotel
local_laundry_service
local_library
local_mall
local_movies
local_offer
local_parking
local_pharmacy
local_phone
local_pizza
local_play
local_post_office
local_printshop
local_see
local_shipping
local_taxi
location_city
location_disabled
location_off
location_on
location_searching
lock
lock_open
lock_outline
looks
looks_3
looks_4
looks_5
looks_6
looks_one
looks_two
loop
loupe
low_priority
loyalty
mail
mail_outline
map
markunread
markunread_mailbox
memory
menu
merge_type
message
mic
mic_none
mic_off
mms
mode_comment
mode_edit
monetization_on
money_off
monochrome_photos
mood
mood_bad
more
more_horiz
more_vert
motorcycle
mouse
move_to_inbox
movie
movie_creation
movie_filter
multiline_chart
music_note
music_video
my_location
nature
nature_people
navigate_before
navigate_next
navigation
near_me
network_cell
network_check
network_locked
network_wifi
new_releases
next_week
nfc
no_encryption
no_sim
not_interested
note
note_add
notifications
notifications_active
notifications_none
notifications_off
notifications_paused
offline_pin
ondemand_video
opacity
open_in_browser
open_in_new
open_with
pages
pageview
palette
pan_tool
panorama
panorama_fish_eye
panorama_horizontal
panorama_vertical
panorama_wide_angle
party_mode
pause
pause_circle_filled
pause_circle_outline
payment
people
people_outline
perm_camera_mic
perm_contact_calendar
perm_data_setting
perm_device_information
perm_identity
perm_media
perm_phone_msg
perm_scan_wifi
person
person_add
person_outline
person_pin
person_pin_circle
personal_video
pets
phone
phone_android
phone_bluetooth_speaker
phone_forwarded
phone_in_talk
phone_iphone
phone_locked
phone_missed
phone_paused
phonelink
phonelink_erase
phonelink_lock
phonelink_off
phonelink_ring
phonelink_setup
photo
photo_album
photo_camera
photo_filter
photo_library
photo_size_select_actual
photo_size_select_large
photo_size_select_small
picture_as_pdf
picture_in_picture
picture_in_picture_alt
pie_chart
pie_chart_outlined
pin_drop
place
play_arrow
play_circle_filled
play_circle_outline
play_for_work
playlist_add
playlist_add_check
playlist_play
plus_one
poll
polymer
pool
portable_wifi_off
portrait
power
power_input
power_settings_new
pregnant_woman
present_to_all
print
priority_high
public
publish
query_builder
question_answer
queue
queue_music
queue_play_next
radio
radio_button_checked
radio_button_unchecked
rate_review
receipt
recent_actors
record_voice_over
redeem
redo
refresh
remove
remove_circle
remove_circle_outline
remove_from_queue
remove_red_eye
remove_shopping_cart
reorder
repeat
repeat_one
replay
replay_10
replay_30
replay_5
reply
reply_all
report
report_problem
restaurant
restaurant_menu
restore
restore_page
ring_volume
room
room_service
rotate_90_degrees_ccw
rotate_left
rotate_right
rounded_corner
router
rowing
rss_feed
rv_hookup
satellite
save
scanner
schedule
school
screen_lock_landscape
screen_lock_portrait
screen_lock_rotation
screen_rotation
screen_share
sd_card
sd_storage
search
security
select_all
send
sentiment_dissatisfied
sentiment_neutral
sentiment_satisfied
sentiment_very_dissatisfied
sentiment_very_satisfied
settings
settings_applications
settings_backup_restore
settings_bluetooth
settings_brightness
settings_cell
settings_ethernet
settings_input_antenna
settings_input_component
settings_input_composite
settings_input_hdmi
settings_input_svideo
settings_overscan
settings_phone
settings_power
settings_remote
settings_system_daydream
settings_voice
share
shop
shop_two
shopping_basket
shopping_cart
short_text
show_chart
shuffle
signal_cellular_4_bar
signal_cellular_connected_no_internet_4_bar
signal_cellular_no_sim
signal_cellular_null
signal_cellular_off
signal_wifi_4_bar
signal_wifi_4_bar_lock
signal_wifi_off
sim_card
sim_card_alert
skip_next
skip_previous
slideshow
slow_motion_video
smartphone
smoke_free
smoking_rooms
sms
sms_failed
snooze
sort
sort_by_alpha
spa
space_bar
speaker
speaker_group
speaker_notes
speaker_notes_off
speaker_phone
spellcheck
star
star_border
star_half
stars
stay_current_landscape
stay_current_portrait
stay_primary_landscape
stay_primary_portrait
stop
stop_screen_share
storage
store
store_mall_directory
straighten
streetview
strikethrough_s
style
subdirectory_arrow_left
subdirectory_arrow_right
subject
subscriptions
subtitles
subway
supervisor_account
surround_sound
swap_calls
swap_horiz
swap_vert
swap_vertical_circle
switch_camera
switch_video
sync
sync_disabled
sync_problem
system_update
system_update_alt
tab
tab_unselected
tablet
tablet_android
tablet_mac
tag_faces
tap_and_play
terrain
text_fields
text_format
textsms
texture
theaters
thumb_down
thumb_up
thumbs_up_down
time_to_leave
timelapse
timeline
timer
timer_10
timer_3
timer_off
title
toc
today
toll
tonality
touch_app
toys
track_changes
traffic
train
tram
transfer_within_a_station
transform
translate
trending_down
trending_flat
trending_up
tune
turned_in
turned_in_not
tv
unarchive
undo
unfold_less
unfold_more
update
usb
verified_user
vertical_align_bottom
vertical_align_center
vertical_align_top
vibration
video_call
video_label
video_library
videocam
videocam_off
videogame_asset
view_agenda
view_array
view_carousel
view_column
view_comfy
view_compact
view_day
view_headline
view_list
view_module
view_quilt
view_stream
view_week
vignette
visibility
visibility_off
voice_chat
voicemail
volume_down
volume_mute
volume_off
volume_up
vpn_key
vpn_lock
wallpaper
warning
watch
watch_later
wb_auto
wb_cloudy
wb_incandescent
wb_iridescent
wb_sunny
wc
web
web_asset
weekend
whatshot
widgets
wifi
wifi_lock
wifi_tethering
work
wrap_text
youtube_searched_for
zoom_in
zoom_out
zoom_out_map
```